# How to get an angular directive to include & replace another directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an AngularJS directive, `directiveFoo` instantiated by an attribute:

```
<div directiveFoo></div>
```

I want my `directiveFoo` to always instantiate another directive, e.g. the template is:

```
<div directiveBar="123"></div>
```

My question is this -- Is this possible to do without creating all the wasted nodes?  I'd like to add `replace` to my directive, but then it blows away `directiveFoo`

What I ultimately want is:

```
<div directiveFoo directiveBar="123"></div>
```

with the two controllers attached.

This is a simplified example.  I'm trying to prevent:

```
<div directiveA>
    <div directiveB>
        <div directiveC="123">
            <div directiveD></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

in cases where I don't really need all the nested DOM nodes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but then it blows away directiveFoo

It shouldn't. "The replacement process migrates all of the attributes / classes from the old element to the new one. " -- [directive doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Because attributes are migrated, `directive-foo` should show up in the generated HTML.

```
app.directive('directiveFoo', function() {
    return {
        template: '<div directive-bar="123">bar</div>',
        replace: true,
    }
});
```

The above directive results in the following HTML (tested in Chrome):

```
<div directive-bar="123" directive-foo>bar</div>
```

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZSAfL/)</kbd>.

In the fiddle I also create a controller for each directive (since you mentioned you wanted that), and I show that `directive-bar` can access `directive-foo`'s controller.

(I put `bar` as text in the template, just to make it easier to right-click on it and select "Inspect element").

Comment: Okay, I thought it was for some reason.  Thanks for the clarification!